# append multiple numbers to ideal list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have four input as following:

```
a=12
b=13
c=87
d=136
```

and I want to have this output:

```
x=[12 87 136 13]
```

Also, the 'comma' in the output list should not exist.

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting the array?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the variables in a Python list like this:

```
l = [a,b,c,d]
```

and then print in the format that you require with this code:

```
print('x=[' + ' '.join(str(x) for x in l) + ']')
```

The output is:

```
x=[12 13 87 136]
```